# Why do I encounter the problem while trying to mask the color region using matplotlib and numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, data-visualization

So Iam trying to mask out a region of the image which looks like this[![test.jpg][1]][1]. It has to be converted to masked region allowing only the display of camera view. The resulted image looks like this.[![result image][2]][2], so what is the problem with this code?

```
#importing modules 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# reading image
image = mpimg.imread("test.jpg")
#grab x and y values and make a copy of the original image
ysize = image.shape[0]
xsize = image.shape[1]
masked_img = np.copy(image)
print(y_value, x_value)
plt.imshow(image)

# defining color selection criteria
red_threshold = 255
green_threshold = 255
blue_threshold = 255
color_threshold = [red_threshold, green_threshold, blue_threshold]

# coordinates of region
left_top = [0,0] 
left_bottom = [0,720]
right_top = [1280,0]
right_bottom = [1280,720]
apex = [620,400]

# fit lines fto idenftify the region of infteresft
#syntax: numpy.polyfit( x , y , deg , rcond = None , full = False, w = None, cov = False)
fit_left = np.polyfit((left_top[0], left_bottom[0]), (left_top[1], left_bottom[1]), 1)
fit_left_apex = np.polyfit((left_bottom[0], apex[0]), (left_bottom[1], apex[1]), 1)
fit_right_apex = np.polyfit((apex[0], right_bottom[0]), (apex[1], right_bottom[1]), 1)
fit_right = np.polyfit((right_bottom[0], right_top[0]), (right_bottom[1],right_top[1]), 1)
fit_top = np.polyfit((right_top[0], left_top[0]), (right_top[1], left_top[1]), 1)

# Find the region inside the lines
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, xsize), np.arange(0, ysize))
region_thresholds = (YY > (XX*fit_left[0] + fit_left[1])) & \
                    (YY > (XX*fit_right[0] + fit_right[1])) & \
                    (YY > (XX*fit_top[0] + fit_top[1])) & \
                    (YY < (XX*fit_left_apex[0] + fit_left_apex[1])) & \
                    (YY < (XX*fit_right_apex[0] + fit_right_apex[1]))

# Color pixels red which are inside the region of interest
masked_img[region_thresholds] = [0, 0, 0]

# Display the image
plt.imshow(masked_img)
# uncomment if plot does not display
#plt.show()
```

When I run the above mentioned code, I encounter the following error

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [44], in <cell line: 28>()
     24 apex = [620,400]
     26 # fit lines fto idenftify the region of infteresft
     27 #syntax: numpy.polyfit( x , y , deg , rcond = None , full = False, w = None, cov = False)
---> 28 fit_left = np.polyfit((left_top[0], left_bottom[0]), (left_top[1], left_bottom[1]), 1)
     29 fit_left_apex = np.polyfit((left_bottom[0], apex[0]), (left_bottom[1], apex[1]), 1)
     30 fit_right_apex = np.polyfit((apex[0], right_bottom[0]), (apex[1], right_bottom[1]), 1)

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in polyfit(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\users\a7266\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py:668, in polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond, full, w, cov)
    666 scale = NX.sqrt((lhs*lhs).sum(axis=0))
    667 lhs /= scale
--> 668 c, resids, rank, s = lstsq(lhs, rhs, rcond)
    669 c = (c.T/scale).T  # broadcast scale coefficients
    671 # warn on rank reduction, which indicates an ill conditioned matrix

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in lstsq(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\users\a7266\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:2292, in lstsq(a, b, rcond)
   2289 if n_rhs == 0:
   2290     # lapack can't handle n_rhs = 0 - so allocate the array one larger in that axis
   2291     b = zeros(b.shape[:-2] + (m, n_rhs + 1), dtype=b.dtype)
-> 2292 x, resids, rank, s = gufunc(a, b, rcond, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
   2293 if m == 0:
   2294     x[...] = 0

File c:\users\a7266\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:100, in _raise_linalgerror_lstsq(err, flag)
     99 def _raise_linalgerror_lstsq(err, flag):
--> 100     raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares")

LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyV6d.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mgnJ.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `np.polyfit` is the `x` array, and both of `(left_top[0], left_bottom[0])` are zeroes, and the `y` array has two different values. You can't possibly fit a polynomial to that!

Comment: Any suggestions  on what I should do Instead? Thanks in advance